# JavaScript, client to server event

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, event-handling, dom-events

I have a server side file stream that I need to destroy on client side button press.  How can I pass a client event to the server?  I am using angular and node/express.  Both express.io and live.io seem deprecated.

Comment: you can call express api like /destroy/:filename from client side and on server you can delete that specific file

Comment: I would look into using the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service for angular.